# configuration dialog is blocking access to editor - how to make this dialog MODELESS? (Java, Eclipse plugin)

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration

I am developing a plugin based on Eclipse, using Java.
I am using there the DebugUITools.openLaunchConfigurationDialogOnGroup and creating a dialog with a shell window, a structureSelection and a groupIdentifier.
for the shell passed to the function, I used the `new Shell(getActiveShell(), SWT.MODELESS)`
I used the `SWT.MODELESS` to make this shell work in a mode that wont block the other windows\views.
I want the user to still be able to use the editor while this dialog is open.

for some reason, the SWT.MODELESS doesn't affect in any way and while the dialog is open, all other windows and particularly the editor is disabled for any kind of edit\interaction.

I tried to work on a different UI thread (I thought maybe this is blocking the main UI thread, but it didn't help either)

Am I using wrongly the SWT.MODELESS? maybe I am missing more configurations to make this dialog not block the other windows?
please advise, Thank you!

Comment: The Shell that you pass to `DebugUITools.openLaunchConfigurationDialogOnGroup` is just the parent shell, it does not change the way the displayed dialog works - it will always be modal regardless of the parent.

Comment: @greg-449 if so, how am I able to change this functionality and make the shell that is created to be MODELESS? since the DebugUITools.openLaunchConfigurationDialogOnGroup is an Eclipse function which I cannot adjust. I though the shell it gets can affect its behavior.

Comment: You can't change the mode with anything you do on this call. You would have to extend the **internal**  LaunchConfigurationsDialog and change the shell style and the `setBlockOnOpen` settings - but since this is an internal dialog it is against the rules to do that. Since the dialog is not designed to be modeless it might not work properly anyway.

Comment: @greg-449 thank you for the explanation. Could you please clarify why it is against the rules? (or refer me to a source explaining that so I could understand it fully).
Also, why if it is not designed to be modeless, it wont work? is there any reason why it is designed that way? (again, any refer to a piece of information to deepen my understanding of it would be great!)
again, thank you.

Comment: Any class with **internal** in the package name is off limits. It can be changed or even removed at any time - this has happened in the past and caused a lot of problem for people who ignored the rules  - https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html LaunchConfigurationDialog is in the org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations package

Comment: A modal dialog is the normal default. Modal dialogs can assume that nothing will change while the dialog is displayed. If the dialog is modeless the user can use other menus and dialogs to change things the dialog is relying on. For the launch configuration dialog that might mean the launch config being changed by something else.